# CASE WHEN in WHERE condition logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have query like below

```
SELECT name, address, phone
FROM users
WHERE
    CASE @ViewType
    WHEN 'AR' THEN phone IS NULL
    WHEN 'PO' THEN phone IS NOT NULL
    ELSE 1=1 END
```

ViewType is parameter, but I received an error in my SQL.

Comment: `CASE` returns a scalar value, *not* a boolean result. Use `AND`/`OR` logic.

Comment: Just a note, the above query is ANSI/ISO SQL compliant (more or less), and would work with other dbms:s. However, it's still a better idea to use regular AND/OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want boolean logic:

```
select name, address, phone 
from users 
where
    (@viewtype = 'AR' and phone is null)
 or (@viewtype = 'PO' and phone is not null)
 or @viewtype not in ('AR', 'PO')
```

If `'AR'` and `'PR'` are the only possible values of the parameter, then the last predicate can be removed.

For performance with such parameterized query, consider using [`option(recompile)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments), so that a new plan is generated for the current value value of the parameter.